# T sql delete same rows except one row with where query

Tags: sql-server

I have table as below

**Customer**

**Customer** table has columns like below

```
sales_ID varchar(50)

product_ID int

ProcessNumber int

CreateDate datetime
```

Customer table has data as below

**1. row**

```
sales_Id "00000020041"

product_ID 1733

ProcessNumber 15
```

**2. row**

```
  sales_Id "00000020041"

  product_ID 1733

  ProcessNumber 15
```

**3. row**

```
  sales_Id "00000020041"

  product_ID 1733

  ProcessNumber 15
```

**Question:**

I want to delete all rows except one row with where query.

I tried below

```
    ;with cte as
    (
    select *,row_number() over(order by sales_ID) RN 
    FROM Customer
    where sales_Id = sales_Id 
    and product_ID  = product_ID 
    and ProcessNumber  = ProcessNumber)

    delete  from cte where RN>1
```

However what I tried is not working for me.

How can I **delete all rows except one row if sales_ID and product_Id and ProcessNumber equals to sales_ID and product_Id and ProcessNumber** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use `PARTITION BY` in your `ROW_NUMBER()` like this

```
;with cte as
(
select *,row_number() over(PARTITION BY sales_Id,product_ID,ProcessNumber order by (SELECT 1)) RN 
FROM Customer
where sales_Id = sales_Id 
and product_ID  = product_ID 
and ProcessNumber  = ProcessNumber)

delete  from cte where RN>1
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a `CTE` and a `WHERE` clause. The below should suffice.

```
DELETE FROM (
select *,
row_number() over(
                PARTITION BY sales_Id,product_ID,ProcessNumber 
                ORDER BY Sales_ID
                 ) rown
FROM Customer
            )tbl where rown > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use DELETE tbl FROM (...)tbl instead of DELETE FROM (...)tbl in this case.

```
    DELETE tbl
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT *,
        row_number() over(
                        PARTITION BY sales_Id,product_ID,ProcessNumber 
                        ORDER BY Sales_ID
                            ) RowNumber
        FROM Customer
    )tbl 
    WHERE RowNumber > 1
```